# How do I REALLY reset the Visual Studio window layout?

Tags: visual-studio

I had a plugin installed in Visual Studio 2008, and it created some extra dockable windows.  I have uninstalled it, and I can't get rid of the windows it created - I close them, but they always come back.  They're just empty windows now, since the plugin is no longer present, but nothing I've tried gets rid of them.  I've tried:

- Window -> Reset Window Layout
- Deleting the .suo files in my project directories
- Deleting the Visual Studio 9.0 folder in my Application Settings directory

Any ideas?

Comment: "Reset Windows Layout" now works fine in VS213.

Comment: STILL DOESN'T ALWAYS WORK EVEN IN VS2017 :-(

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Have you tried this?  In Visual Studio go to **Tools** > **Import and Export Settings** > **Reset all settings**

Be sure you **back up** your settings before you do this. I made the mistake of trying this to fix an issue and didn't realize it would undo all my appearance settings and toolbars as well. Took a lot of time to get back to the way I like things.

Comment: Be sure you back up your settings before you do this.  I made the mistake of trying this to fix an issue and didn't realize it would undo all my appearance settings and toolbars as well.  Took a lot of time to get back to the way I like things.

Comment: Also be aware backing up your settings often doesn't work.  I've never successfully done it.  I believe there is a known bug if you add macros to some menus.

Comment: Guys backing up the setting works 100%. Only a small issue: you need to select "all files"  when you visualize the list of backupped settings. And the hidden files have to be visible. YES, the saved settings are hidden. This in VS2010.

Comment: After back up and reset, import the same settings you just backed up, but deselect Window Layouts (in General Settings) from the stuff to import. Worked great for me

Comment: To get back your Resharper shortcuts after the above operation (VS2015): Resharper -> Options -> Keyboards & Menus -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Apply scheme

Answer (score 35):

Try **devenv.exe /resetuserdata**. I think it's more aggressive than the Tools > Import and Export options suggested.

Also check **Tools > Add In Manager** and make sure there aren't any orphans there.

Comment: Lifesaver! /resetuserdata worked for me. I was having issues with very slow startup, slow display of Add -> New Item dialog, crashing when opening MVC2 solutions.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to reset the window layout. Then

go to "WINDOW" -> "RESET WINDOW LAYOUT"

Comment: The asker said that they tried this, and it didn't work for them.

Comment: The asker said this in 2008; now, at least for VS2019, it is the way to go; besides, there are commands too to save and apply windows layouts.

Answer (score 12):

How about running the following from command line,

```
Devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

You could also save those settings in to a file, like so,

```
Devenv.exe /ResetSettings "C:\My Files\MySettings.vssettings"
```

The /ResetSettings switch, Restores Visual Studio default settings. Optionally resets the settings to the specified .vssettings file.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 11):

I had similar problem except that it happened without installing any plugin. I begin to get this dialog about source control every time I open the project + tons of windows popping up and floating which I had to close one by one.

[image]

**Windows -> Rest Windows Layout**, fixed it for me without any problems. It does bring the default setting which I don't mind at all :)

Comment: started having this issue too and there was nothing on the net about it.  Came here looking for a different issue and found this  -  thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you have an old backup copy of CurrentSettings.vssettings, you can try restoring it.

I had a completely corrupted Visual Studio layout. When I tried to enter debug, I was told that VS had become unstable. When I restarted, my window layout would then be totally screwed. I tried restoring the VS current user settings in the registry from a backup, but that didn't help. However, restoring CurrentSettings.vssettings seems to have cured it.

There seems to be a bunch of binary stuff in there and I can imagine it gets irretrievably corrupted sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Note: if you have vs2010 and vs2008 and you want to reset the 2008, you will need to specify in command line the whole path. like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /resetsettings
```

If you don't specify the path (like `devenv.exe /resetsettings`), it will reset the latest version of Visual studio installed on your computer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried most of the suggestions, and none of them worked.  I didn't get a chance to try /resetuserdata.  Finally I reinstalled the plugin and uninstalled it again, and the windows went away.

Comment: How did you not get a chance to try running a single command line call, but you had the chance to completely re-install the plugin...Anyway, /resetsettings worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

> I close them, but they always come back

When you say "they always come back" do you mean "next time you restart Visual Studio" or "immediately"?

One quirk of Visual Studio (at least VS2005) is that settings aren't saved until you exit.  That means that if VS crashes at all while you are using it, any layout changes you made will be lost.  The way around this is to always *gracefully exit* when you have set up everything like you want it to be.

Not sure if this will help your particular situation though.

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering how to do that in the VS Code, you can reset the View Layout by pressing: `Ctrl + Shift + P`

Then type: `View: Reset View Locations`

This command reset all the panels to their default positions.

Answer (score 1):

If you've ever backed up your settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings), you can restore the settings file to get back to a prior state. This is the only thing that I've found to work.

Comment: Grabbed the settings from another machine.  Only thing that worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset your development environment of your visual studio, then you can use Import and Export setting wizard. see this for all steps:

http://www.authorcode.com/forums/topic/how-to-reset-development-environment-settings-of-your-visual-studio/

Comment: Link broken, please remove