# visual studio 2005 problem with windows flying open

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-xp

I'm going through the problem of setting up a new computer and I'm having a problem with VS 2005.  Whenever I start debugging all the windows (properties, watch, errorlist, stack, ...) pop up all over the place undocked.  At this point I've tried docking them and closing them.  When I stop debugging more windows pop up all undocked.  This keeps happening over and over and over...  I've tried closing and docking them but they keep popping out.  Wasn't sure how to google this and my patience has grown thin with this whole process of moving to a new comp.

Sincerely,
Frustrated

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863/how-do-i-really-reset-the-visual-studio-window-layout) about resetting your settings might be helpful (even though it says VS2008, it still applies to 2005).