# How do you unpin and move the form in the Visual Studio designer?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-designer

In Visual Studio, the forms are stuck to the top left corner of the IDE working area like they are pinned there. How do you unpin them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863/how-do-i-really-reset-the-visual-studio-window-layout

Comment: Why would you want to move them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not "pinned", they're actually being drawn there in that position by the designer.

This is a simulated drawing only. The form does not actually function in the designer the same way that it does at run-time. You cannot move forms around or interact with their non-client area in any way (e.g., you also can't click the minimize or close boxes).

This is simply not supported. And I can't imagine a good reason why it should be.

Comment: Ergonomic disadvantage.  I was afraid of this answer.

Comment: @pl0xtic If you just want the form in the middle of your screen, you can undock the document tab that contains it and resize/reposition *it*.