# Reseting default settings for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I don't know what happened to My VS but today when I drag and drop a datasource to a form, it fills the form with textfields instead of a datagridview. 
How do I restore VS to bring a datagridview as default when I drag a datasource to a form?

I tried this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/06/18/10039048.aspx but it didn't work.

Comment: Check if this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863/how-do-i-really-reset-the-visual-studio-window-layout

Comment: I have tried that. Also in VS when I drag a datagridview to my form and click on choose data source on the drop down, I get the error object reference not set to instance of object.