# Visual Studio 2013 is opening new windows in the bottom set of tabs when in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 has started opening new Windows in the bottom pane, where the breakpoints, locals, watch, call stack, etc. live.  This is only when in debug mode, when I'm not debugging they open in the top tab group like all my other .cs, .js, etc. code.

Any idea why it's doing this and how to fix it?

Comment: the window configuration in debug mode is saved differently than when not in debugging. move them how you want *while debugging* to have them go back to that format when you start debugging next time.

Comment: how about closing them when they appear?

Comment: worst case, follow instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863/how-do-i-really-reset-the-visual-studio-window-layout to reset the whole thing to factory.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, I'm pretty sure Visual Studio falls into the `unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.` exception.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow where zealots close first then ask questions later...

Comment: I can't really move them, it's when I double-click on a file in Solution Explorer it's by default opening them in the bottom pane.  I can drag them into the top pane with all the other source files, but the next time I open a file it opens them in the bottom pane.