# Visual Studio Solution Explorer scroll visually duplicates upper toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Sometimes, when I scroll the solution explorer, it corrupts the view. I'm guessing it could be related to the video card or something but don't know how exactly.

Can't explain it better than just to show image:

[image: Visual Studio corrupt view]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried one of these procedures? 
Reset windows layout
Go to Window > Reset Winow Layout

Reset all settings
Go to Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings
[How do I REALLY reset the Visual Studio window layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863/how-do-i-really-reset-the-visual-studio-window-layout)