# Unable to connect to Team Foundation Server 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am running Windows 7 Pro 64bit, Visual Studio 2013 Professional and am having trouble connecting to Team Foundation Server 2013.

I am part of a domain. Now supposedly nothing has changed ;-), and yesterday I was able to connect but today I am not. Fellow team memebrs are able to connect, just not my machine it seems.

Here is what I have tried:

- Run up VS2013 on a **different** machine and use my credentials to login to that machine and ultimately connect to TFS - Works fine.
- Telnet from my **current** workstation to the TFS server on port 8080 works fine
- However no amount of rebooting of my **current** workstation or trying anything seems to have any effect. If I go to the source control explorer all I have is "Connecting..." and I get no further. If I however open a web browser and use the web interface I can connect. All of this from my **current** machine (the one not connecting when in VS)

Now as I can connect from a different machine using my credentials I am guessing that somehow my workstation is being blocked, my guess is the domain controller is doing this. I have administrator access to the domain controller and can check things on there, but after looking at what is shown in the GUI all appears to be "normal" from what I can tell (I am however a noob when it comes to Domain Controllers in a Windows environment)

Has anyone got any suggestions or a walk through of what I can try? I have followed numerous suggestions found using Google to no avail.

**UPDATE**

- Reinstall of VS 2015 has not improved the above behaviour

**UPDATE #2 (RESOLVED)**

- This turned out to be a malware infection on this machine. A HTTP interceptor had been installed. This was obviously failing/causing an issue when Team Explorer/Visual Studio was attempting to connect to TFS. Once the Malware was removed "it all started working"

Thanks to all for their suggestions.

Comment: What exact error message did you see?

Comment: Does the devenv /resetsettings and devenv /safemode command helps?

Answer (score 2):

It could be an issue with the stored credentials for some reason. To clear them from the registry;

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Run Task Manager and find out all TFS services.  Click on End Process Tree to shut down all the services
3. Delete just the TokenStorage folder:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage

Restart Visual Studio and retry

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to remove/add TFS server on your Team Explorer? [Maybe after removing your cached credentials under [Credentials Manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server.aspx) ]
2. Have you tried to [clear your client cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsalm/archive/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines.aspx)?

[I would prefer to comment, but not enough reputations yet..]

Comment: 1. Cannot get to add/remove TFS server as VS just shows "Connecting..." in Team Explorer window and then non responsive.
2. Had done this, Looking again the cache folder is empty for 5.0

Comment: 1. Can you post a screenshot with the menu options when you right click Team Explorer? 2. Can you try from the menu "Team-> Connect to Team Foundation Server" on top, and removing/adding collections, trying to connect a single Team Project at a time?3. It could be Team Explorer window, have you tried to unpin/undock/dock to somewhere else? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863/how-do-i-really-reset-the-visual-studio-window-layout) reset layout with a backup of your preferences

Comment: Have you tried to run GPUpdate on your local machine? And can another user login via your VS?