# How to change Visual Studio 2017 default Window layout in C++ sytle?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've been using Visual studio 2017 to code in C++ for long,
but all of sudden after I tried C# programming, the default layout of Visual studio 2017 was changed into C# project style ( - solution explorer, Resource view, on the right.. and even font looks different from what I've been using with C++ so far. )

It seems default language was set to C#? or something but I can't find the right menu to change my visual studio setting..
I do remember when I firstly install my visual studio 2017, I selected C++ as a default language or theme.
I wonder what's the right menu to change this.it's not critical but I feel really uncomfortable using this layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a menu to change the layout. Just drag the windows to the  left or right side (or top and bottom, if feeling adventurous), and they will stay there.

Comment: The window layout is stored in a file associated with the solution.  So as long as you worked only on one C++ project, you would have seen only one layout.  One that remember any (accidental) changes you made.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863/how-do-i-really-reset-the-visual-studio-window-layout

Answer (score 0):

There is no C++ style layout in Visual Studio.

You could [Customize window layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customizing-window-layouts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022):  drag and dock the window.

Or there is Tools -> import and export -> reset all settings.